# Why does the order of a dispatched print() change when run in a Playground?

Tags: swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

In a Udacity's GCD course there was a small quiz:

```
let q = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
q.async { () -> Void in
    print("tic")
}
print("tac")
```

Which will be printed first?

The correct answer is: `tac`, then `tic`. Seems logical.

But, why is it so only when I create an Xcode project? In a playground it prints `tic` then `tac`. What am I missing?

Comment: _"The correct answer..."_ What you're missing is that the answer they gave is simply wrong. :) This code makes no guarantees about the order of execution of those statements.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you seem to be right. Thanks! Just do not know why they pointed out the correct answer as `tac tic` in the Udacity cource.

Answer (score 0):

In GCD

> DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async{}

is below

> DispatchQueue.main.async{}

Even thought it has quality of service (qos) as UI thread it does not means it is a main thread. So may be there is a difference in performance with play ground and ui project

please check apples documentation as well.

[Apples documentation on GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html)

Answer (score 0):

key to your answer is in the question what really are you asking the "system" to do, an by system that is the whatever the code is running on the playground, your computer/phone or emulator.   You are executing an asynchronous "block" of code - print("tic") with some priority ".userInteractive". If the system handles the asynchronous block first or continues with "normal" execution depends on priority and available resources. With asynchronous calls there is no real why to guarantee that it is executed before or after the code continues that is the nature of being asynchronous i.e execute the block as soon as the system allows it, all without blocking your current work. So the difference you are seeing in playground vs a project/emulator is that the project/phone/emulator must keep the UI/primary thread responsive so it continue with print("tac"), while the development playground favors the thread executing print("tic"). Bottom line is it has to deal with priority of execution and the available resources and how its implemented on the system you're running the code.